# How to increment a dynamically named variable in `zsh`

Tags: zsh, variable

Say one creates a dynamically named variable in `zsh`, thus:

```
name="hello"
typeset $name=42
echo ${(P)${name}} # Prints the variable $hello, which is 42
```

Now, suppose one want to increment or change the said variable, but without knowing it's direct name, i.e. I'd expect something similar to the following to work:

```
(( ${(P)${name}} = ${(P)${name}} + 1 )) # Set $hello to 43?
```

The above doesn't work - what will?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ name=hello
$ hello=42
$ (($name++))
$ echo $hello
43
```

Just like in any Korn-like shell. Or POSIXly:

```
$ name=hello
$ hello=42
$ : "$(($name += 1))"
$ echo "$hello"
43
```

The point is that all parameter expansion, command substitutions and arithmetic expansions are done inside arithmetic expressions prior to the arithmetic expression being evaluated.

```
((something))
```

is similar to

```
let "something"
```

So in `(($name++))` (like `let "$name++"`), that's first expanded to `hello++` and that's evaluated as the `++` operator applied to the `hello` variable.

POSIX `sh` has no `((...))` operator but it has the `$((...))` arithmetic *expansion* operator. It doesn't have `++` (though it allows implementations to have one as an extension instead of requiring it to be a combination of unary and/or binary `+` operators), but it has `+=`.

By using `: "$((...))"` where `:` is the null command, we get something similar to ksh's `((...))`. Though a strict equivalent would be `[ "$((...))" -ne 0 ]`, as `((expression))` returns false when the expression resolves to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will do it:

```
 typeset $name=$(( ${(P)${name}} + 1 ))
```

Any alternative methods will be much appreciated.